# How to check if a string has more than one of a certain character in a row in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string that might have multiple commas in a row. I want to find every time it has more than one comma, I want it to be replaced with only one comma. How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

To test if a string contains multiple commas in a row:

```
var result = /,,/.test(input);
```

To replace them with just one:

```
var result = input.replace(/,+/g, ',');
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace two or more consecutive commas with a single comma, you can use this:

```
str = str.replace(/,{2,}/g, ",");
```

The `{2,}` after the comma means two or more of whatever the preceeding character was in the regex.

The `g` flag tells it to replace all occurrences of that in the string.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/pxhLH/

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple loop and replace.  Plug this into your page to see it work.

```
var str = ",,, I have ,, some extra ,, commas ,,";
            while (str.indexOf(",,") > -1) {
             str = str.replace(",,", ",")                  
            }
            alert(str);
```

The only part you need is the while loop.  If you want you can make it into a function where str is the parameter and then kick out your new string.